# Unity Local 2 Player combination of controller and keyboard controllers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a local multiplayer Unity based game. I want to allow Player 1 to use the keyboard to control their character while Player 2 uses an xbox 360 controller. The issue that I am having is that the controller is only registering as Joystick 1. Here is what I have done so far:

1. I set up two separate inputs, one polling joystick1 and the keyboard for player 1 with another polling joystick2 (and some alternate keyboard keys) for player 2.
2. I have the system working with both players on the keyboard, but am unable to get player 1 to use the keyboard while player 2 uses the controller (or visa versa).

My question is, how can I force a controller to become joystick2 or joystick1? Is there a way to control which input is registered to which number?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for that solution as well. It seems like Portal2 has managed to get a keyboard+mouse / xbox360controller for local cooperative play, but people have been struggling to get it to work because of this same problem, seems like switching player number in the 360controller is tricky.

Portal2 post on this matter
https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=239373369

Comment: It's not an answer, never write questions as answer. Please raise comments or ask a new question.

Comment: sorry, it was my first time using stackoverflow, i didn't see the "add a comment" thingy